# Moving a node within a linked list to the front in order to move it to a different linked list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, double-pointer

I have to write a program in which each player had a set number of cards in hand and each turn they have to draw a card then discard a card because they must maintain this set amount of cards at the end of each turn.

What I have written works flawlessly for the first player (first turn), but then it gets to the second player (second turn) and the program ends. After debugging, I found out that it's because it can't read `hand2`.

Is it because the pointer is not pointing to the correct address? I'm not certain how to fix this issue.

```
void discardCard(struct card_s** hand1, struct card_s** hand2,.., struct card_s** pack, struct card_s** discardPile, ...) {

    struct card_s* prev = NULL;
    struct card_s* traverseOne = NULL; //transverse list nodes one by one
    struct card_s* skiptrasverseOne = NULL; // to transverse list nodes by skipping one

    /*
    * identify which card the user wants to discard
    * move to the front of the hand
    * move it to discardPile 
    */

    /*FIRST PLAYER WORKS JUST FINE*/
    if (currentPlayer == 0) {
        traverseOne = (*hand1);
        skiptrasverseOne = (*hand1);

        //finds the node of where the desired card to be discarded is
        while (skiptrasverseOne != NULL && skiptrasverseOne->next != NULL) {
            prev = traverseOne;
            skiptrasverseOne = skiptrasverseOne->next->next->next;
            traverseOne = traverseOne->next;
        }

        //moves node to head
        prev->next = prev->next->next;
        traverseOne->next = (*hand1);
        (*hand1) = traverseOne;
    }

    //SECOND PLAYER - PROGRAM ENDS AT THE WHILE LOOP BECAUSE IT CANNOT READ hand2.
    else if (currentPlayer == 1) {
        traverseOne = (*hand2);
        skiptrasverseOne = (*hand2);
    
        while (skiptrasverseOne != NULL && skiptrasverseOne->next != NULL) {
            prev = traverseOne;
            skiptrasverseOne = skiptrasverseOne->next->next->next;
            traverseOne = traverseOne->next;
        }

        prev->next = prev->next->next;
        traverseOne->next = (*hand2);
        (*hand2) = traverseOne;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Could you create a [mre] that we can run? It should include `main()` and the call or calls to `discardCard()`.

Comment: *"works flawlessly for the first player"*: that means you are lucky, as it will also fall into an error when the number of cards in hand1 is somewhat different. This statement: `skiptrasverseOne = skiptrasverseOne->next->next->next` is unsafe, as you didn't verify that `skiptrasverseOne->next->next` is not null. Also, you didn't explain the logic as to how the card to be discarded should be chosen.

Comment: When you have variables called `foo1`, `foo2`, `foo3`, etc, you should *really* consider using arrays.

Comment: the idea behind `skiptrasverseOne = skiptrasverseOne->next->next->next` is to move the 2nd node to head of the list. Then that's what later gets discarded. 
But I do see how is unsafe and shouldn't have approached the problem this way.